# C++ exception is not caught after calling dll function

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, dll, qt-creator

I'm stuck with the following problem:
There is DLL with exported functions.

Here is the code example:
[DLL]

```
__declspec(dllexport) int openDevice(int,void**)
```

[APP]

dev.h:

```
__declspec(dllimport) int openDevice(int,void**)
```

dev.cpp:

```
try {
    void *p = NULL;
    int devError = openDevice(some_integer,&p);
    if(devError)
        throw (int)devError;
} catch(int i) {
    cerr << "Device opening error: " << i << endl;
}
catch(...) {
  //other handler
}
```

The exception is not passed to catch block and I have no reason why. Please help to solve this problem.
I'm using Qt Creator with MSVC 9.0.

Comment: And `devError` is non-zero?

Comment: yes, `devError` is non-zero

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `(int)` unsafe cast in your throw expression.

Then, add a `cerr` statement within the `if(devError)` block to prove it is actually being executed.

Then, make a test program to prove that exceptions work at all.  Just a `main()` that throws and catches.

Comment: Oh, I've forgot to mention that CDB debugged is being used. This problem only occurs in debug mode, though in release the exception is caught

Comment: Why is casting `int` to `int` "unsafe"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because it removes the compile-time check that you are indeed doing a safe conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1) Is `devError` really != 0?

2) Perhaps an exception already occured within the DLL function...